# MVVM and updating the ViewModel

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-mobile

Question about MVVM and data binding in Kendo Mobile:

- `account.js`:

  ```
  define([], function () {
      return {
          userPhone: 111
      };
  });
  ```
- `index.html`:

  ```
    <p>Phone: <span id="test-span" data-bind="html: userPhone"></span>.</p>
  ```
- `home-view.js`:

  ```
  define(["kendo", "app/account"], function (kendo, account) {

  var viewModel = kendo.observable({
      userPhone: account.userPhone
  });

  return {
      show: function() {
         viewModel.set("userPhone", account.userPhone); // LINE A

         account.userPhone = "222"; // LINE B

      },    
      viewModel: viewModel
  }
  });
  ```

  1. **Without LINE A and LINE B**, `#test-span` displays (null)
  2. **With only LINE A**, `#test-span` displays "111"
  3. **With only LINE B**, `#test-span` displays (null)

I understand why #2 behaves the way it does.  I just doesn't understand why #1 and #3 behave as they do.  I thought the whole point of MVVM and data-bindings is that I could update `account.userPhone` and have it update views globally without having to do `viewModel.set`.

Assuming I have `home-view2.js`, `home-view3.js`, etc, how can I update all viewModels will changing just the account property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line B would work or not depending on the framework used, in this case KendoUI is not dirty-checking based. This means setting `account.userName` directly will not work, the updates need to be done by calling special setters in model classes such as in line A.

For example AngularJs is based on dirty checking, so line B would work if put on a controller or called inside `$apply`, and there is no need for code like line A.

The way angular dirty checking works is by taking a snapshot of a plain javascript object, and then at appropriate moments (on event callbacks, ajax callback and setTimeouts) take another another snapshot.

If the two snapshots differ, all the components observing `account.userName` are updated, for example DOM elements - and this is how angular bidirectional binding with plain javascript objects works.

Have a look at [angular KendoUI](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/) for an Angular library based on the Kendo widgets.

If you are interested in dirty checking and how it works, have a look at this [podcast](http://javascriptjabber.com/032-jsj-angular-js/) by the Angular authors, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs) from them, where a comparison with framework like Knockout or Backbone is made.

Comment: thanks that's good info about Angular, but don't you think this is possible in Kendo's MVVM implementation without bringing in `kendo-angular`?

Comment: That is right, in pure kendo it's not possible, as kendo is not dirty checking based. I mentioned angular as a way of explaining how updating account.userName cannot work in kendo due to the way the framework works (based on model classes / setters), but could work in other libraries

Comment: I misread your comment, indeed I think it's not possible in Kendo MVVW due to the way the framework is currently designed. it's not meant to be used with plain javascript objects.

Comment: ahh too bad. well thanks for pointing me in the direction of dirty checking.  good to know how it all works.